# ASP.Net using multiple form tag and post them to another page

Tags: asp.net, postdata, multiple-forms

I don't know it's even possible but I try to achieve to post data from one page to another using the second form.
The problem is I need a form tag for the user interface containing callback panels etc. I want to put a second form with some hidden-field:

```
<form id="postForm" method="post" action="target.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" id="id" />
</form>
```

I submit the form from javascript with jquery:

```
$("#id").val(id);
$("#postForm").submit();
```

Is there a way access the value of the hidden field on the target page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the hidden field a `name` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
```

You'll then be able to use [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) in your target page to access the posted data:

```
string postedId = Request.Form["id"];
```